# Property with type 'UIBarButtonItem!' cannot override a property with type 'UIResponder?' after changing to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode-storyboard

I have two buttons declared here:

```
@IBOutlet var previous: UIBarButtonItem! 
// No error even though its nearly identical

@IBOutlet var next: UIBarButtonItem! 
// contains error Property 'next' with type 'UIBarButtonItem!' 
// cannot override a property with type 'UIResponder?'
```

This worked fine until I upgraded to swift 3. I tried removing all references and button, relinking using the editor with no luck

Comment: Check this property in father-classes and clean and then re-build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the name of your outlet (and it's connection in your storyboard) from `next` to `nextItem`, as the Swift 3 API's for`UIResponder` now have a [`next` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621099-next).

Comment: Thanks! that was it.